# Convert a string with RTF Format in it to a plain text string using VB

Tags: vb.net

This is my first project in VB.Net
I have a string with RTF format. I need to delete/remove the group of bullets when it appears in that string, using VB.Net.

My string:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2070{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}{\f2\fnil\fcharset2 Symbol;}}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17\par
\pard{\pntext\f2\'B7\tab}{\*\pn\pnlvlblt\pnf2\pnindent0{\pntxtb\'B7}}\f1 one\par
{\pntext\f2\'B7\tab}two\par
{\pntext\f2\'B7\tab}three\par
{\pntext\f2\'B7\tab}\par
\pard\fs17\par
}
```

I have 3 bullets called one, two, three. I need to remove the format but maintain the values each in line.

I've tried something like this in VB

```
If (Rtfctrl.FindNumberOfOccurences(Txt, "\bullet", True) = 1) Then
     resultString = resultString.Replace("\bullet", "")
End If
}
```

... but bullet is not in the string. The list bullets are a group with a more complex sintax.

Who can I do that?
Regards,
Filipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't usually suggest using a Control for something other than user interaction, but a RichTextBox can convert RTF text into plain text. You can create a RichTextBox without ever adding it to the Form. Then assign the RTF text to the Rtf property and read the plain text from the Text or Lines property. For example:

```
Dim rtf As String = "{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang2070{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}" _
    & "{\f1\fnil\fcharset0 Tahoma;}{\f2\fnil\fcharset2 Symbol;}}\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17\par" _
    & "\pard{\pntext\f2\'B7\tab}{\*\pn\pnlvlblt\pnf2\pnindent0{\pntxtb\'B7}}\f1 one\par{\pntext\f2\'B7\tab}two\par" _
    & "{\pntext\f2\'B7\tab}three\par{\pntext\f2\'B7\tab}\par\pard\fs17\par}"
Dim rBox As New RichTextBox
rBox.Rtf = rtf
Dim txt() As String = rBox.Lines
```

After running this code, txt(1) contains "one", txt(2) contains "two" and txt(3) contains "three".

Comment: rBox.Text should also work to return a single string instead of an array of lines. I haven't seen .Lines before - I'm sure I'll use it in the future - thanks!

Comment: Thanks for both for the solution. It was very helpful! :)